# How do i loop a function from another function in c++

Tags: c++

Quick question, well at least i'm hoping it is.

How do I loop a function using a for loop.

for example, i'm trying to convert kelvin to Fahrenheit. If the user inputs 350 the program loops starting from 0 up to 350 and converts each one to Fahrenheit.
my code is below. I'm sure its something really simple.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
using namespace std;

int user_interface();
void convert(double , double &);
void print_table(double,double &);

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{   
    user_interface();
    /*convert(Farenheit);*/

  
    return 0;
}

int user_interface()
{   
    double user_input;
    double Farenheit;

    do
    {
    cout<<"Please Enter Maximum Kelvin Value: ";
    cin>>user_input;
    if(user_input<0)
    {
        cout<<"Positive Integer Values Only! Please Try Again.\n";
    }
    else
    {
        ;
    }
    }
    while(user_input<=0);

    convert(user_input, Farenheit);
    cout<<"Farenheit is: "<<Farenheit<<"\n";
    cout<<"User_input is: "<<user_input<<"\n";
    print_table(user_input, Farenheit);

    return 0;
}

void convert(double user_input, double &Farenheit)
{
    double temp;
    int count;
    /*temp=(((9)*(user_input-273.15))/5)+32;
    Farenheit=temp;*/
    for(count=0; count<=user_input; count+=50)
    {

        temp=(((9)*(count-273.15))/5)+32;
        Farenheit=temp;
        cout<<"Convert Farenheit"<<Farenheit<<"\n";
    }
    return;
}

void print_table(double user_input, double &Farenheit)
{
    double x;

    cout<<"Temp_user_input"<<Farenheit<<"\n";

    cout.width(10);
    cout<<"K";
    cout.width(14);
    cout<<"F"<<"\n";

    for( x=0; x<=user_input; x+=50)
    {
        cout.width(10.2);
        cout<<x;
        cout.width(14.2);
        cout<<Farenheit<<"\n";
    }
}
```

I have everything working just that part in the print_table function.

Side note, please don't mind all the other extras. i'll clean it up once i get the last part to work.

many thanks for the help.

Comment: You can call whatever functions you want inside of a loop.

Comment: thanks tadman for the reply, I actually did try to call convert() i.e. cout<<convert(x) in the print_table function, but i get a mess of errors.

Comment: We do mind "all the other extras", because before asking, you are expected to extract a [mcve]. The extras make your question off-topic. The simple reason for that rule is that it forces you to extract the core of the problem first, which often leads to solving it.

Comment: "Mess of errors" doesn't help us understand the problem. Including the *exact error text* does.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just updated your code to create a minimal example.This is just to show you how it is done.
I just called the function where you are printing the values. As you are passing arguments by ref. all you had to do is to call the function with different inputs and the value of  Farenheit variable will be changed in the loop. and you can print that new value associated with the input.

```
#include <iostream>

#include <iomanip> using namespace std;

int user_interface();
void convert(double & , double & );
void print_table(double, double & );

int main(int argc, char * argv[]) {
  user_interface();
  /*convert(Farenheit);*/

  return 0;
}

int user_interface() {
  double user_input;
  double Farenheit;

  do {
    cout << "Please Enter Maximum Kelvin Value: ";
    cin >> user_input;
    if (user_input < 0) {
      cout << "Positive Integer Values Only! Please Try Again.\n";
    }

  } while (user_input <= 0);

  print_table(user_input, Farenheit);

  return 0;
}

void convert(double & temp, double & Farenheit) {
  Farenheit = ((9 * (temp - 273.15)) / 5) + 32;
}

void print_table(double user_input, double & Farenheit) {
  double x;

  cout << "Temp_user_input" << Farenheit << "\n";

  cout.width(10);
  cout << "K";
  cout.width(14);
  cout << "F" << "\n";

  for (x = 0; x <= user_input; x += 50) {
    cout.width(10.2);
    cout << x;
    cout.width(14.2);
    convert(x, Farenheit);
    cout << Farenheit << "\n";
  }
}
```

Comment: Hey Kelvin thanks for the help. It's really appreciated and a big help. But unfortunately i can't change the convert datatype to double. it has to stay a void. would you happen to know how to work around a void function? Any help would be greatly appreciated. oh and also it has to stay double, double &.

Comment: Please check updated Ans

Comment: @kelvin I see here a solution in code, however, can you also explain what you changed and why, so the OP can learn from it?

Comment: @JVApen I just changed location of function call

Comment: @kelvin thank you for the help. I'm still getting an error but that's ok. i can totally figure it out from there. I do appreciate your help. I just needed a direction and you more than have given that. I really truly appreciate it. just incase the error was call of overload. again thank you

Comment: @kelvin, actually that was quick i just missed an ampersand sign.